# How to run terminal command in interactive mode from NeoVim?

Tags: neovim, terminal

I have a terminal command which runs code with a breakpoint in it. When I run this command in NeoVim the code execution does not stop at the breakpoint, instead I get an error, that its not a TTY terminal. The exact same command stops at the breakpoint in Vim.

I guess I need `shell` command, which was removed in NeoVim. Is there any other way to run it?

`:help :terminal` shows:

> :sh[ell]
> Removed. vim-differences
>
> :terminal :te :te[rminal][!] [{cmd}]
> Run {cmd} in a non-interactive 'shell' in a
> new terminal-emulator buffer. Without {cmd}, start an interactive 'shell'.
>
> Type i to enter Terminal-mode, then keys are sent to the job running in the terminal. Type `<C-\><C-N>` to leave Terminal-mode. `CTRL-\_CTRL-N`

**Update**: I have this simple `hello_world.py` python3 program and I want to make it print "Hello world" (variable `name` value has to be changed to `"world"` in the breakpoint:

```
def hello_world():
    name = None
    breakpoint()
    print(f'Hello {name}')
hello_world()
```

When I try to execute `:!python3 hello_world.py` program in the NeoVim I get this output:

```
:!python3 hello_world.py
> /home/niekas/cct/individual-thematics-api/backend/tmp.py(4)hello_world()
-> print(f'Hello {name}')
(Pdb)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello_world.py", line 6, in <module>
    hello_world()
  File "hello_world.py", line 4, in hello_world
    print(f'Hello {name}')
  File "hello_world.py", line 4, in hello_world
    print(f'Hello {name}')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/bdb.py", line 88, in trace_dispatch
    return self.dispatch_line(frame)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/bdb.py", line 113, in dispatch_line
    if self.quitting: raise BdbQuit
bdb.BdbQuit

shell returned 1

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

**Update**: I have tried using `:!bash -ic ipython` to test if interactive mode works, but it doesn't. IPython exited automatically, see the output:

```
:!bash -ic ipython
bash: cannot set terminal process group (5377): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
^[[22;0t^[]0;IPython: individual-thematics-api/backendPython 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.20.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: Do you really want to exit ([y]/n)?
^[[23;0t
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Comment: You’ll need `:terminal` in neovim for interactive commands.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I have tried `:terminal`, however it does not start in interactive mode if I provide a command. I don't know how to automatically provide a command for terminal, which was started without a command.

Comment: Actually, the shell is non-interactive, but you can still interact with the command (eg, `:terminal python3` is still a python repl). You may have to press `i`, as you quoted in the post. Without a command, it should just launch a shell—bash, zsh, whatever windows is doing these days, etc. Then you type a shell command—such as the name of a program and its arguments. Maybe you should [edit] and show how you run the command in vim and neovim and what output you are getting/how its not working?

Comment: If it complains about tty not being a terminal than , the command probably should be run in interactive mode. Try :!bash -ic 'your command ' if you are on bash shell. Or :!zsh -ic 'your command' for zsh shell

Comment: @JustKhaithang `:!bash -ic ipython` didn't start in interactive mode for me. See the output in the update question.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble That actually worked! I simply have to use `:te ipython` instead of `:!ipython`. Thank you so much :) Post this as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: use `:terminal {command}` for interactive stuff.

Long answer: neovim’s `:!` actually communicates via subprocesses and the commands are not directly interactive due to the way the IO streams are handled. `:terminal` is envisioned as the replacement for this, since it does use a TTY and is interactive.