# How can I launch interactive terminal programs in neovim just like I can do in vim?

Tags: neovim, shell

I'd like an easy way to switch from neovim to vim for the reason of, some plugins are not compatible with neovim (Ultisnips).

I hope'd I could just run `:!vim` however that doesn't work - errors appear:

```
Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
```

For example trying to launch `htop` - It seems `:!` does not work the same in neovim as it does in vim. For example I can run `:!htop` from vim which works great, the same does not work in neovim, it seems the alternative for neovim is to use `:terminal htop` however this is not exactly the same (attached screenshot)

Where the differences I have noted is:

- Line numbers appear
- Neovim's "mode" still seems to be active which requires entering insert mode (by pressing `i` to) "take control" of the actual underlying application
- Opening vim from within neovim (with the end goal of being able to switch from neovim -> vim easily) results in an error of:

  > Error detected while processing /nix/store/193d09wqy410
  > emotePlugins[5]..20_GetManifest[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiUXR.png)..20_GetMan line    7:
  > E117: Unknown function: stdpath Press ENTER or type command to
  > continue

It feels like neovim is running in some kind of wrapper, while vim seems to run it directly?

[image]

Comment: Well, `:terminal htop` (no bang), but you can either do that or C-z/`:suspend` because https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/29318/10604

Comment: That is not the same though, for example keystrokes are ignored. Usually `q` would exit htop while in neovim  the `:terminal htop` mode it does not.

Comment: It should, unless you’re in terminal normal mode. All but a very few special keys are sent directly to the program.

Comment: Leaning towards marking as a duplicate of https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/29318/18609

Comment: @filbranden I agree, I haven't yet been convinced that it's not the same (the screenshot doesn't tell us what's wrong). Chris, please read `:help terminal` and see if that helps you figure out what's going on with the keys you mentioned.

Comment: Have updated the question with the differences / issues I've noticed. Reading through `:help terminal` I can't seem to find any info relating to the issues or limitations.

Comment: I have quite a few problems with your premise here... *"some plugins are not compatible with neovim (Ultisnips)"* No, I don't think that's not the case, UltiSnips should work in NeoVim just fine. *"Unknown function: stdpath"* The `stdpath()` function is a NeoVim-specific function, it seems like you're doing the opposite, using NeoVim-only plug-ins in Vim. NeoVim dropped behavior of setting up a tty for `:!` and removed `:sh`, so `:term` is all that's available there.

Comment: That's essentially the same as what that other question is asking, so I'll go ahead and mark as a duplicate. Yes, there are differences between running a terminal inside Vim/NeoVim and spawning an external command... But in NeoVim, that's what's essentially available... The other question addresses that already, so there's no reason to keep this one open. My advice to you would be to figure out what's preventing you from using certain plug-ins in NeoVim, since they most likely should work there... There doesn't make much sense to use *both* NeoVim and Vim, particularly both at the same time...